# Mongo: How to find all pairs of item with same value in one collection

Tags: mongodb, shell

I wan to find all pairs of teams who have the same number of goalsFor as each other and the same number of goalsAgainst as each other, get the teams and numbers of goalsFor and goalsAgainst.

my Teams collection like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4d95cdfa20e8e9822da6bf"), "team" : "Spain", "ranking" : 2, "games" : 6, "wins" : 5, "draws" : 0, "losses" : 1, "goalsFor" : 7, "goalsAgainst" : 2, "yellowCards" : 3, "redCards" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4d95cdfa20e8e9822da6c0"), "team" : "Brazil", "ranking" : 1, "games" : 5, "wins" : 3, "draws" : 1, "losses" : 1, "goalsFor" : 9, "goalsAgainst" : 4, "yellowCards" : 7, "redCards" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4d95cdfa20e8e9822da6c1"), "team" : "Portugal", "ranking" : 3, "games" : 4, "wins" : 1, "draws" : 2, "losses" : 1, "goalsFor" : 7, "goalsAgainst" : 1, "yellowCards" : 8, "redCards" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4d95cdfa20e8e9822da6c2"), "team" : "Italy", "ranking" : 5, "games" : 3, "wins" : 0, "draws" : 2, "losses" : 1, "goalsFor" : 4, "goalsAgainst" : 5, "yellowCards" : 5, "redCards" : 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

give this aggregation pipeline a go:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    goals_for: '$goalsFor',
                    goals_against: '$goalsAgainst'
                },
                teams: {
                    $push: '$team'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                $expr: { $gte: [{ $size: '$teams' }, 2] }
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                teamPair: '$teams',
                goalsFor: '$_id.goals_for',
                goalsAgainst: '$_id.goals_against',
                _id: 0
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/EfHv92AoyP1